# Read and write in user Uploaded file ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactjs application. It is kind of like a text editor. A user can upload files and read/edit the file. So I was able to read the txt file that the user uploads by using this:

```
displayFile = (i) => {
    this.setState({currentFileIndex: i})

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = async (e) => {
      const text = e.target.result;
      this.setState({fileText: text})
    };
    reader.readAsText(this.state.files[i].file);

  };

onFileSelected = (event) => {
    var file = event.target.value;
    var startIndex =
      file.indexOf("\\") >= 0 ? file.lastIndexOf("\\") : file.lastIndexOf("/");
    var filename = file.substring(startIndex);
    if (filename.indexOf("\\") === 0 || filename.indexOf("/") === 0) {
      filename = filename.substring(1);
    }
    const filesArray = this.state.files;

    filesArray.push({ fileName: filename, file: event.target.files[0] });
    this.setState({ files: filesArray });
  };
```

The input html is:

```
<input
          type="file"
          accept=".glm, .csv, .player, .txt"
          id="Editor_Screen_Upload_Input"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          onChange={this.onFileSelected}
        />
```

So, how can write and save in state if the user edits a file?

Comment: `html` in reactjs not correct. in reactjs called jsx.and what's means `style={{ display: "none" }}`?

Comment: You can ignore that. Input is triggered by clicking another element. The question is something else!

Comment: ok . if you put your sample code on the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) it's great.